# Cycles renders coming out speckled and low resolution, how can I improve this?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, resolution

The render below was done with cycles with sampling set to 128. I've done renders in the past that have come out nicely with what I believed are the same settings, so I must have clicked or slid a slider by mistake but I haven't been able to figure out what I've done.
I should add I've tried raising the sampling to no avail (though it wouldn't be a proper solution to the issue if it had compensated I imagine).

I've screen capped the settings for the render below, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can be dependent on what BSDFs and which features you're using.  SSS for example introduces a lot of noise and takes a lot more samples to resolve.

Comment: Were you/are you running a denoiser?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not familiar with BSDF or SSS but I did try the denoiser set to NLM which seems to partially resolve my issue by doing what it says on the tin, however the resolution is still poor, even after increasing the render resolution to 2560 1440.

Comment: F12 should render with the settings under Dimensions - Resolution XY at that you provided in the post, you're saying that increasing those values and rendering again spit out the same image?

Answer (score 2):

Can you show the geometry in edit mode? It might be just not enough geometry.
Similar artifacts with smooth shading are produced when lacking geometry like here:
[image]

[image]

Or you could try to recalculate normals to see if any of the artifacts are a normals issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not the answer I am looking for. Zoom into the image and look at the shadows, these areas are noisy and the resolution of the render is poor, regardless of how I set the resolution or increasing the samples.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if the noise is the problem then it's just how blender is. Sometimes there is this level of noise even on 1000+ samples depending on the scene.
I suggest just using AI denoiser:
1)Go to layer properties
2)Locate "Denoising Data" under Passes and check it
3)Now in compositor place in a denoise node between input and output and connect all corresponding inputs and you should have noiseless render after compositing even on 10 samples. Tough I'd recommend bigger sample count as small sample count can cause blurriness and artefacts after denoising